# Tableview Dynamic switches having issue , if i select the switch and make it on immediately it not getting on in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4.2

I have created a `UITableView` and adding the switch dynamically into each cell the basis is of requirement . if i select a switch and turn it on and immediately select next switch and turn it on, it's having an issue with the state of the switch its changing and a previously selected switch is getting off, its happening only if i select all the switch fast.

[image]

here is the image in this i am adding all the switches dynamically as per the data and if i on the first switch it data will load them in the other table . but if i select all the switch fast fast and turn them on  some switch will stuck in to off state only . if i tap on the outside of the table its disappear and if again i load the table that time i can see all selected and previously enable (on) switch is turn off(not all but random its happen)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if let _ = cell {} else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    if let d = self.data {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = d[indexPath.row]
        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(self.isFolderIsAdded(folderName: d[indexPath.row]), animated: true)
        switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell?.accessoryView = switchView

    }
    return cell!
}

func isFolderIsAdded(folderName:String) -> Bool{
    for   val in listOfSelectedFolder{
        if(folderName == val ){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    if let d = self.data {
        if(sender.isOn){
            self.delegate?.selectedSubFolder(name: d[sender.tag])
           } else {
            self.delegate?.deleteFilesFromFolder(folderName: d[sender.tag])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add else clock in **cellForRowAt indexPath** and set **switchView.setOff** and check what Happens.

Comment: In IOS 12+ simulator have some issue related UI update, Tabbar tapped, button pressed, switch on/off update etc, I have faced the same issue but in the device it works fine, So check this once in the real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reuse problem.
when you scroll the tableView, The cell is then reused.
the switch on it will be reset.

You need follow MVC Design patterns.
use a model to help you. 
Like this

```
class CellModel {
  var name = ""
  var switchOn = false
}

var dataSource = [CellModel]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell
    cell.model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  var model: CellModel? {
     didSet {
     switchView.isOn = model?.switchOn ?? false
    }
  }
  init(xxxx) {
     switchView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
  }


  @objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
       model.switchOn = sender.isOn
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When Reusing a tableViewCell Always remember to use.

1- prepareForReuse method in tableViewCell class

2- write `else` conditions for all `if conditions` specially if you are updating any UI in `if condition`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

if let _ = cell {} else {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
if let d = self.data {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = d[indexPath.row]
    let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.setOn(self.isFolderIsAdded(folderName: d[indexPath.row]), animated: true)
    switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell?.accessoryView = switchView

}else{
// Update your UI if data not found like turn your switch off etc ... 
    }
    return cell!
}
```

3- **Or** It might be an issue of your simulator after update of Xcode 9.0 simulator are now not good as they were till Xcode 8.X

Answer (score 0):

I am tried your code with some changes, it is working fine. It is not an issue with tableView.dequeueReusableCell. Please try the code below.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var listOfSelectedFolder = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
var listOfSelectedFolder2 = ["sample text 0","sample text 1","sample text 2","sample text 4","sample text 5","sample text 6","sample text 7","sample text 8","sample text 9","sample text 10","sample text 11","sample text 12","sample text 13","sample text 14","sample text 15","sample text 16","sample text 17","sample text 18","sample text 19","sample text 20","sample text 21","sample text 22","sample text 23","sample text 24","sample text 25","sample text 26","sample text 27","sample text 28","sample text 29","sample text 30","sample text 31","sample text 32","sample text 33","sample text 34","sample text 35","sample text 36","sample text 37","sample text 38","sample text 39","sample text 40"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/// tableview datasouce methodes

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfSelectedFolder2.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if let _ = cell {} else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    let foldername = listOfSelectedFolder2[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = foldername
        let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(self.isFolderIsAdded(folderName: foldername), animated: true)
        switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell?.accessoryView = switchView

    return cell!
}
func isFolderIsAdded(folderName:String) -> Bool{

    return listOfSelectedFolder.contains(folderName);
}

@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
        if(sender.isOn){

            self.listOfSelectedFolder.insert(self.listOfSelectedFolder2[sender.tag], at: sender.tag)
        } else {
            self.listOfSelectedFolder.remove(at: sender.tag)
            self.listOfSelectedFolder.insert("", at: sender.tag)
        }
}
}
```

In case you still have the same issue, maybe the UI updates happening on the background thread. So make sure the UI updating code is running on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {code})
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {code}
```